# When I use bazel to compile a project that depends on curl, I get an error: error: unknown type name 'u32'

Tags: c++, curl, bazel

The whole error message:

```
In file included from external/curl/lib/sendf.c:30:
/usr/include/linux/tcp.h:135:2: error: unknown type name 'u32'
  u32 real_ip;
  ^~~
/usr/include/linux/tcp.h:136:2: error: unknown type name 'u16'
  u16 real_port;
  ^~~
```

It seems to be related to the gcc version?

gcc version 8.3.1 20191121 (Red Hat 8.3.1-5) (GCC)

Comment: After I change it to "__u32 real_ip; __u16 real_port;",  the question is resolved, but how it happends and how to solve it with other methods?

Comment: What do you mean by "change it to ```__u32```", you mean you directly modified the /usr/include/linux/tcp.h?